# ng build fails (cannot find module) on docker (ubuntu) but works on windows 10

Tags: angular, docker, npm, aws-codebuild

I'm not sure if this is related to docker, ubuntu or node/npm, so here are all the details I can provide.

*I know there are causes of this module error, but nothing explains why it works on various windows machines but not on docker on Ubuntu.*

The error is:

```
ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts:110:51 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './tools/tools.module'.

110         path: 'tools', loadChildren: () => import('./tools/tools.module').then(m => m.ToolsModule)
```

And the offending line in app-routing.module.ts is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        // ... various child routes
      },
      {
        // fails here:
        path: 'tools', loadChildren: () => import('./tools/tools.module').then(m => m.ToolsModule)
      },
```

*However,* this works fine from Windows 10 x64 locally or on TeamCity. So now specific machine details:

The failure occurs on docker on AWS CodeBuild. My build spec is

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 3.1
      nodejs: 14.x
    commands:
      - npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.13
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the build phase...
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - cd src
      - dotnet restore
      - dotnet build
      - cd Web
      - npm install
      - ng build --verbose --prod
      - cd ..
      - dotnet test
      - echo Entered the post_build phase...
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Node on docker and on my local (Windows) is v14.15.4 (with npm 6.14.10).

I'm using the standard AWS CodeBuild image which I think is Ubuntu 18.04.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update**
I upgraded to Angular 10.2; including the CLI which is now 10.2.1; removed rxjs-compat and a bunch of other upgrade-suggestions; but I still get the same `Cannot find module` error.

Comment: It's because on windows some of your dependencies uses windows dependencies, and in linux (ubuntu this case) don't, you should try to delete your package-lock and then try again on that linux enviroment

Comment: Thanks @PauloGaldoSandoval I removed package-lock.json before running npm install and now I get the error `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 but 3.9.7 was found instead.`
My package.json has `"typescript": "^3.8.3"`. I'm looking into this further now but feel free to comment with any more advice!

Comment: so deleting package.lock.json and installing typescript ~3.8.3 instead of ^3.8.3 gets me back to square one: `error TS2307: Cannot find module`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, for crying out flaven...

### CASE SENSITIVITY!

The tools module was committed to git in the folder `Tools` but `app-routing.module.ts` was referencing `tools`; which of course worked on Windows, but not on Linux.

*cries in lowercase*